# How do I reduce the execution time or computational cost when creating a list of tuples with conditions, if I insert a large number of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, tuples

I have this two lists of tuples as an example:

```
l1 = [(3364, 183, 8619),
      (8077, 124, 6142),
      (3776, 166, 7385),
      (8874, 11, 9453),
      (12917, 225, 12433),
      (2567, 54, 8188),
      (11919, 82, 2062),
      (10698, 108, 12151)]
```

Second list:

```
l2 = [(3364, 183, 20),
      (8077, 124, 21),
      (3776, 166, 22),
      (8874, 11, 23),
      (12917, 225, 24),
      (2567, 54, 25),
      (11919, 82, 26),
      (10698, 108, 27)]
```

**1 -** I create a new list with "list comprehension" from the two lists by executing the condition that for each tuple within the list the first element of the tuple are equal to the first element of each tuple within the second list I can insert the values p [0], p [1] (of the first list) and n [0] of the second list,
practically:

```
new_list = list(set([(p[0],p[1],n[2]) for n in l2 for p in l1 if p[0] == n[0]]))
```

**2 -** then I break down the triples into a single list:

```
new_list = [n for n2 in new_list for n in n2]
```

**3 -** I break down the tuples into a single list because later I'm going to create an array by randomly choosing the values from that list, i.e .:

```
new_elements = np.random.choice(new_list, size =512)
```

**What is the problem ?**

When in lists l1 and l2 there are large quantities of numbers of tuples, steps **1** and **2** take too long to run.
Can you tell me where I am wrong or if there are more efficient methods to have a better execution?

I hope I have best explained my problem.

**example:**

```
 l1 = [(10,11,2),             l2 = [(10,11,3),
       (9,10,4)]                    (9,10,5)]
```

after :

```
new_list = list(set([(p[0],p[1],n[2]) for n in l2 for p in l1 if p[0] == n[0]]))
```

output:

```
new_list = [(10,11,3),
            (9,10,5)]
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I'm sorry I modified the list-comprehension with the if condition. Now do you mean?

Comment: Your condition says `if p[0] == n[0]` but your prose talks about comparing two elements. If it's the former, use `np.searchsorted`. After sorting one of the lists of course.

Comment: I check the tuples inside the two lists and see if the first element of the tuple inside the list l1 is equal to the first element of the tuple inside the list l2 I insert in the new_list the element p [0], p [1] (of the tuples in l1), n [2] (of the tuples in l2):
p [0], p [1], n [2]. @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: Please read through your question and carefully make sure your prose matches the code you show. Repeating the same thing over and over won't make them match.

Comment: The first element of the tuples of the first list with the first element of the second list. @MichaelSzczesny

Comment: @MadPhysicist I modified the question and inserted an example.

Comment: In both of your examples you can just use `new_list = l2`. Btw: Explanation (take `n[0]`) and code (takes `n[2]`) still doesn't match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use dictionary to index your `p[0]` and `n[0]`

```
d1 = {p[0]: p[1] for p in l1}
d2 = {n[0]: n[2] for n in l2}
```

here I dropped `p[2]` and `n[1]` as they are irrelevant in future steps.

Then we find the intersection of the two keys as you required

```
intersection = d1.keys() & d2.keys()
```

And finally build the `new_list` as you need for your step 3

```
new_list = list(intersection) + list(map(d1.get, intersection)) + list(map(d2.get, intersection))
```

Comment: Thank you very much  for the advice is now very efficient! @Raymond!

Comment: Please consider to accept it as the answer if it is. Thank you

Comment: Yes, can you subtract -1 from my question?